# Why would URL.openConection() throw an IOException.

Tags: java, url, ioexception, urlconnection

Assuming a http scheme (i.e. `new URL (“http://www.google.com/”)`) ,would not the `IOException` be thrown on `myHttpURLConnection.connect()` and not on `myHttpURLConnection = myURL.openConection()`.

I mean `instanceURL.openConection()` doesn't seem to open a connection immediately, and if so how can there be an `IOException`.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark by saying it might have something to do with using file://

Comment: I'm guessing it's a API design decision to allow connection handlers to raise an exception when you attempt to resolver a connector. I'd suggest it's to allow the connection resolver an opportunity to perform some level of validation (should it need to) before it constructs and returns a new connector...IMHO

Comment: It could be because, the constructor of URL actually throws MalformedURLException, which is a type of IOException.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `openConnection`, a connection for the specified URL will be prepared. If `openConnection` fails to prepare the connection because the given URL is invalid, an `IOException` will be thrown.

Please see the [URL API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29) for more info.

Comment: Well what does prepared mean, and what does invalid URL mean.  Malformed exception occurs at the construction of the URL object, and access to the resource appears as if it happens on the .connect() call.

Answer (score 1):

`IOException` is wrapping many exception , for eg `MalformedException` is one of them
If you open as connection with malformed uri ( eg giving incorrect protocol as- `abc://1.1.1.1:1111` ) will throw `MalformedException` wrapped under `IOException`